# in-app subscription - is there a limit of inventory queries from apps?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscriptions

**Is there a limit of inventory queries per day that my applications can send?** (by calling mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener) )

**I wonder if I can check every time my application starts if a user still has the valid subscription?** Or maybe should I implement logic for less requests?

I know that since In-app billing v3 data is cached locally by Google Play service:
http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#QueryPurchases

> Upon a successful purchase, the user’s purchase data is cached locally
>   by Google Play’s In-app Billing service. It is good practice to
>   frequently query the In-app Billing service for the user’s purchases,
>   for example whenever the app starts up or resumes, so that the user’s
>   current in-app product ownership information is always reflected in
>   your app.

but on the other hand there is a limit 200k request via Google Play Android Developer API (Quota):
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html#using

Edited:
I don't use any backend servers.

Comment: could you resolve your question ?? i have the same question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have found a solution to this, but this may help others:

Yes there is a quota on the number of queries per day per application, the 2nd link you are referring to (http://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api.html#quota) states that there is a quota of 200,000 requests per day but you can request more if you run out of that.

Also it is actually recommended by google to check every time your application starts using getPurchases as defined in v3 - that's why they optimized it. It is explained very well in this presentation which also provides example code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgcJPIRpfSk at 08:10.